# jQuery Deferred Not Re-Initialising

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Subsequent to [Johan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598511/johan) answering a [previous question on the Deferred object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788320/defining-handler-functions-in-a-prototye), I have created the following code:

```
var modalConfirm = (function ($) {

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    var cls = function () {

        this.title = arguments[0].title;
        this.text = arguments[0].text;

        var t = new Date().getTime();

        var html = '<div class="modal show" id="modal-confirm' + t + '">\n';
        html += '   <div class="panel">\n';
        html += '       <h2>' + this.title + '</h2>\n';
        html += '       <p>' + this.text + '</p>\n';
        html += '       <div class="buttons">\n';
        html += '           <input type="button" id="confirm-yes' + t + '" value="Yes">\n';
        html += '           <input type="button" id="confirm-no' + t + '" value="No">\n';
        html += '       </div>\n';
        html += '    </div>\n';
        html += '</div>\n';
        html += '<div id="modal-overlay' + t + '" class="overlay"></div>\n';

        $('body').append(html);

        $('#confirm-no' + t).click(function () {
            mHideConfirm(t);
            dfd.reject({ modal: null });
        });
        $('#confirm-yes' + t).click(function () {
            mHideConfirm(t);
            dfd.resolve({ modal: null });
        });
    }

    cls.prototype = {
        yes: dfd.promise().done,
        no: dfd.promise().fail
    };

    return cls;

})(jQuery);

function mHideConfirm(t) {
    $('#modal-confirm' + t).remove()
    $('#modal-overlay' + t).remove();
}

$('#lst').dblclick(function() {
    new modalConfirm({ title: 'A title', text: 'A text' })
    .yes(function() {
        console.log('YES');
    })
    .no(function() {
        console.log('NO');
    });
});
```

This works as I would expect the first time, by showing the `modal-confirm` div, resolving or rejecting (based on the button clicked) and then hiding the div (`mHideConfirm`). (I added the `t` in case there was some ID uniqueness issue - which there wasn't)

The issue arises when the `dblclick` occurs for the subsequent times. The process automatically fires the `Deferred` event from the previous instance. So, if I click *yes* the first time, when the `dblclick` occurs the second time, *yes* is fired without the button being clicked.

It seems that the `dfd` variable is not re-initialised with the new `modalConfirm` object or at least not inside the `click` event of the button or the `cls.prototype`.

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're using the same deferred object each time. Sure, you're using the new keyword, but the deferred object is stored on the prototype therefore all instances will get the same deferred object. You need to store the deferred object/promise object on each instance rather than the prototype. Create the deferred object in the constructor rather than outside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing the same deferred/promise object for all instances of the class, instead, you need to create a new one for each instance.

```
var modalConfirm = (function ($) {

    var cls = function () {

        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        this.title = arguments[0].title;
        this.text = arguments[0].text;

        var t = new Date().getTime();

        var html = '<div class="modal show" id="modal-confirm' + t + '">\n';
        html += '   <div class="panel">\n';
        html += '       <h2>' + this.title + '</h2>\n';
        html += '       <p>' + this.text + '</p>\n';
        html += '       <div class="buttons">\n';
        html += '           <input type="button" id="confirm-yes' + t + '" value="Yes">\n';
        html += '           <input type="button" id="confirm-no' + t + '" value="No">\n';
        html += '       </div>\n';
        html += '    </div>\n';
        html += '</div>\n';
        html += '<div id="modal-overlay' + t + '" class="overlay"></div>\n';

        $('body').append(html);

        $('#confirm-no' + t).click(function () {
            mHideConfirm(t);
            dfd.reject({ modal: null });
        });
        $('#confirm-yes' + t).click(function () {
            mHideConfirm(t);
            dfd.resolve({ modal: null });
        });
        this.yes = dfd.done;
        this.no = dfd.fail;
        return this;
    }

    return cls;

})(jQuery);
```

which you can then simply to:

```
(function ($) {

    var modalConfirm = function () {

        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        this.title = arguments[0].title;
        this.text = arguments[0].text;

        var t = new Date().getTime();

        var html = '<div class="modal show" id="modal-confirm' + t + '">\n';
        html += '   <div class="panel">\n';
        html += '       <h2>' + this.title + '</h2>\n';
        html += '       <p>' + this.text + '</p>\n';
        html += '       <div class="buttons">\n';
        html += '           <input type="button" id="confirm-yes' + t + '" value="Yes">\n';
        html += '           <input type="button" id="confirm-no' + t + '" value="No">\n';
        html += '       </div>\n';
        html += '    </div>\n';
        html += '</div>\n';
        html += '<div id="modal-overlay' + t + '" class="overlay"></div>\n';

        $('body').append(html);

        $('#confirm-no' + t).click(function () {
            mHideConfirm(t);
            dfd.reject({ modal: null });
        });
        $('#confirm-yes' + t).click(function () {
            mHideConfirm(t);
            dfd.resolve({ modal: null });
        });
        this.yes = dfd.done;
        this.no = dfd.fail;
        return this;
    }

    window.modalConfirm = modalConfirm;

})(jQuery);
```